# How to stop Firefox update notifications?

Tags: firefox, browser

I have Firefox 56, the last good version of the browser, where things I need in terms of performance, and functionality both still work. I'm not going to update, EVER. There are other browsers out there, but Firefox worked so well for scripting.

Anyhow, Firefox keeps alerting me about updates. I have turned the updates off, in `about:preferences` but Firefox keeps bugging me with notifications like these:
[image: No, I dont wanna update FF]
and this:
[image: You suck FF updates....]

I don't want to keep getting bothered by notifications, how do I make them stop?

Comment: If you really want to stay on the "old" firefox (pre-quantum) why not try out Firefox ESR 52? At least that is patched and stay current (until Firefox ESR move on to Quantum which is on Firefox ESR 60 and ditch the old 52) https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From experimenting with Firefox config, just as a possible addition or alternative when solutions that have previously been suggested here are not enough.

After opening the `about:config` (typing `about:config` into the address bar and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>), apply either or both of the following config items:

- Search for `app.update.silent`, then set it to `true`
- Search for `app.update.url`, then change it to a fake/non-existent
  URL

  > For example, if the original is
  >   `https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/6/%PRODUCT%/...`, I changed it to
  >   `xxxhttps://xxxaus5.mozilla.org/update/6/%PRODUCT%/...`

Comment: Will this still allow manual updates? Without that url will it know where to look for updates so that I can manually request updates?

Comment: In firefox 69 app.update.silent does not exist.

Comment: It's also `app.update.url.manual` now.

Answer (score 35):

None of the former **about:config** Configuration changes work nowadays to control update behaviour

This should completely disable the Updates messages in Firefox as per today.

Other policies can be modified in this way. Check the [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md) link and the **about:policies** section.

If you ever, ever want the original behavior, just undo these steps.

### Method 1 - Registry change (Windows)

- Create the following Registry Key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox`
- Create inside, a 32-Bit DWORD `DisableAppUpdate`, with value `1`.
- Restart Firefox.

The following can be saved as a .reg file to apply this change:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox]
"DisableAppUpdate"=dword:00000001
```

Or execute the following line in an elevated command prompt/PowerShell:

```
reg ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox /v DisableAppUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

### Method 2 - Policies.json (Windows / Linux / Others)

- Create the folder `distribution` at the same place the Firefox executable is located, i.e. in Windows: `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\`.
- Create inside, a file `policies.json` with this text:

```json
{ 
    "policies": {
        "DisableAppUpdate": true
    } 
}
```

- Restart Firefox.

### Method 3 - Policies.json (Mac OS)

- Create the folder `distribution` at the same place the Firefox executable is located, i.e. in MacOS: `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources`.
- Create inside, a file `policies.json` with this text:

```json
{ 
    "policies": {
        "DisableAppUpdate": true
    } 
}
```

- Or execute the following line in an elevated command prompt:

```
mkdir -p /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/distribution && echo '{ "policies": { "DisableAppUpdate": true } }' > /Applications/ Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/distribution/policies.json
```

- Restart Firefox.

After this, the following information should appear:

Under **about:preferences**, under Updates:

```
Updates disabled by your system administrator
```

Under **about:policies**:

```
Policy Name            Policy Value
DisableAppUpdate       true
```

Comment: Or more precise: [ManualAppUpdateOnly](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/commit/42630919ca4845b25e8387086b0c31c1eb875d94)?

Comment: Does method 1 prevent me from manually updating if I want to check for updates at any time?

Comment: After adding this file to `/etc/firefox/policies` as instructed in the link. `about:policies` shows that the policies are disabled. I.e. adding this file had no effect.

Comment: Thanks, variant 2 still works on Ubuntu 20.04 in 2023. I removed the preinstalled Firefox and then installed it directly from their offical site.

Comment: If somebody could edit and add a PowerShell code for Method 2, and a Linux Folder & Code for the same to create a Method 4 for Linux, would be appreciated

Answer (score 11):

I had the same question!

I assume that you want to completely disable the updates, otherwise you won't opt the option to disable automatically install updates option from the settings, and won't get the notification at all!

Well, actually if you truly want to disable autoupdate, you can **add a policy**.

#### To add a policy, follow the steps:

1. Go to the firefox installation directory (for any supported OS).
2. Create a directory called `distribution`.
3. Change directory into `distribution`.
4. Create a file called `policies.json`. And paste this code:

```
{
    "policies": {
        "DisableAppUpdate": true
    }
}
```

Save the file, and quit the editor.

5. Restart Firefox if it's already running.
6. To confirm, you can go to the URL `about:policies` and check if there's an entry like this:

```
Policy Name     Policy Value
DisableAppUpdate    true
```

After you are done, from the *Menu => Help => About Nightly* you get to see this:
[image: Disabled Updates]

When you want to update, you may set the boolean value to false.

#### Reading More about Policies

For documentation, you can read the options here in `about:policies#documentation`. You can learn more about how to add policies [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox-enterprise/policies-customization-enterprise/policies-overview-enterprise).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Save the file...wherever the hell you feel like it. These details aren't important or anything.

Comment: "Save the file... wherever the hell you feel like it"? - have you tested that before commenting? I have moved the file to the default installation directory [from distribution/], and it's not working. In my system, if I miss any of the step I posted, the auto-updates are re-enabled.

Comment: You don't even use a relative term like "profile folder". If you're going to spend the time helping people you should make the proper effort.

Comment: I have said to go to the installation directory (please read the step 1 again, carefully this time) If you downloaded it to the /home/users/download folder, that's your installation directory. If you move it to /opt/firefox-abcd then that's your installation directory.

Note: If you don't know what your installation directory is, go to the URL `about:support` and check for the update directory. By default, the update directory is your installation directory.

I have written the answer in a way so that a person without any technical knowledge can follow. thanks.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. My apologies. I was not operating on sufficient sleep.

Answer (score 4):

This is just extension of previous answer.

Find the user preference file, named as `prefs.js`, in user specific folder.

- Windows: `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xyz.default\prefs.js`
- Linux: `~\.mozilla\firefox\xyz.default\prefs.js`

Then add these following three lines. These preferences are of the boolean type. If you find any of these lines are already present, replace that with the following:

```
user_pref("app.update.auto", false);
user_pref("app.update.disable_button.showUpdateHistory", false);
user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);
```

Also if you want to remove the update URL, add these three lines. These preferences are string type:

```
user_pref("app.update.url", "");
user_pref("app.update.url.details", "");
user_pref("app.update.url.manual", "");
```

If these don't work delete/move these three files:

1. `update-settings.ini`,
2. `updater.ini`,
3. `updater.exe` (`updater` in Linux).

Comment: If I delete the url how will it know where to look for updates when I run updates manually or does this eliminate my ability to manually update?

Comment: Also in newer versions, 67 and 68 I no longer have the app.update.auto setting it is now app.update.auto.migrated and setting it to false does not persist.

Comment: Also, go to about:support, notice the the "Update Folder" entry.  Delete that directory, in case a previous check for updates populated it, and found an update. Once populated, even turning off these settings won't help, but if you delete it after doing all these settings, then even if it comes back later, the settings will take effect, and you won't get the annoying reminder.

Answer (score 2):

For others, a simpler solution if you are just annoyed by that second type of notification, you can do this in `about:config` by setting `app.update.doorhanger` to `false`.

Comment: Any idea what else doorhanger effects?

Comment: This option actually replace the small top right message with a modal window. I feel this option is even more abusive...

Comment: At the time of answering, this option did not replace the doorhanger with a modal in the version I was using. This may have been changed in an update.

Answer (score 0):

You have done the method via Firefox Menus (which is the about:preferences), but there are a few more below.

**From `about:config` Menu**

- Type `about:config` in the address bar, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Search for the `app.update.auto` setting.
- Double-click the `app.update.auto` option to toggle the setting. 
  If set to `true`, automatic updates are enabled. 
  If set to `false`, automatic updates are disabled.

**Via `prefs.js` file**

- Close Firefox.
- Navigate to the following location based on your operating system.

  - Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10 – `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox`
  - Unix/Linux – `~/.mozilla/`
  - macOS / OS X – `~/Library/Mozilla/` or `~/Library/Application Support/`
- Open the `Profiles` folder.
- Open the folder that represents the profile you would like to edit. 
  The name of the folder will vary. 
  It is usually a bunch of alphanumeric characters,
  followed by **`.`** and the user-visible profile name
  (which is `default` by default).
- Open the `prefs.js` file with a text editor like Notepad.
- Look for a line that contains `app.update.enabled`. If it doesn’t
  exist, add a line for it in the file and set it as desired using
  these examples:

  - Automatic updates enabled: `user_pref("app.update.enabled", true);`
  - Automatic updates disabled: `user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);`
- (Save the file.)

**Source:** [TechniPages: Enable or Disable Automatic Updates in Firefox](https://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-automatic-updates-in-firefox).

Comment: in about config, app.update.auto is false, but the update alerts persist...? Ill look into those files

Comment: I didn't try the js file but I can say that editing about:config does nothing: it still displays the notification (even if it doesn't install automatically the update)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Sourav Goswami's answer you can paste into policies.json this code

```
{
    "policies": {
        "AppUpdateURL": "http://127.0.0.1/"
    }
}
```

Thus you will got message "You are using latest version of Firefox" in "About" screen.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to Sourav Goswami's answer:

Under macOS 12.2 "Monterey" I found out that Firefox 96.0.2 replaces the carefully crafted `distribution/policies.json` file. This happened even if I set the permissions of this file read-only (`444`).

It seems, however, that if I additionally make the containing `distribution` directory read-only (permissions `555`), then it helps a little: in this case Firefox *adds* some more settings to the `policies.json` file but at least leaves the `"DisableAppUpdate": true` stanza intact. OTOH the permissions of the `distribution` directory are reset to `755`, i.e. `root` can write to it again.

This is what I have in my `policies.json` file after all this:

```
{
    "policies" : 
    {
        "DisableAppUpdate" : true,
        "ExtensionSettings" : 
        {
            "cloudmetering@snowsoftware.com" : 
            {
                "install_url" : "file:///opt/snow/FFCloudmetering.xpi",
                "installation_mode" : "blocked"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is deeply disturbing, because indeed the `/opt/snow` directory is present on my machine, it contains a `snowagent`, and it's quite obvious that Firefox installed this garbage behind my back.

I am not sure I'd like to have Firefox any more on my machine. The only problem is that some websites don't work properly with Safari. But that's a topic for another thread, so I stop here.

Please feel free to comment if you saw this behaviour on other platforms. Thanks.

**Update** (bad pun intended): The "policies" trick doesn't work, this morning Firefox started nagging me again with its oh-so-important update. OTOH the `policies.json` file, which is still read-only, now contains only this:

```
{
        "policies" : 
        {
                "DisableAppUpdate" : true,
        }
}
```

at least the "snow" thingy is gone.

**Second update**: Firefox 98.0.1 simply deleted the `distribution` directory and today I was nagged yet again because 98.0.2 is now available, hooray. My next attempt to fight Mozilla was to lock both the `distribution` directory and the `policies.json` file within it with the `chflags uchg <file>` command. Looks good, Firefox claims that updates have been disabled by the system administration. We'll see how long that lasts.

**Third update**: After installing Firefox 99.0.1, this time under MacOS 11.6.3 "Big Sur" and creating the `distribution/policies.json` directory, all was quiet until today (2022-05-10) when I was greeted with the following message:

[image: Restart is needed]

And all this despite the Firefox Preferences settings still make me believe that updates are disabled:

[image: Updates disabled by system administrator]

**No, I don't want to spend my time babysitting Firefox** and ranting about it on `superuser.com` :-)

Desperately looking for a solution that stops these unnecessary updates.

Comment: The Firefox source code is 100% open, so you can verify if this code was from Firefox.  Given the `xpi` extension, it's almost certainly a web extension.  By default, Firefox installs several different web extensions.  I tried to get their devs to just include such code as part of Firefox (instead of adding it as separate extensions), but I was told they need to do it this way (no explanation was provided).  As such, I wrote a script that deletes web extensions I didn't explicitly install.  It runs just before the Firefox executable starts each time Firefox is launched by the user.

Comment: "Snow" is from `snowsoftware.com`, looks like it's some sort of spyware. After removal it didn't come back. @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: you are right, thanks, but no thanks, I am not going to review the Firefox source code :-) I am quite busy these days.

Answer (score -1):

renaming update.exe to update3.exe do the job