# How make new Firefox profiles have custom configs and pre-installed extensions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

I use lots of Firefox profiles
I need to install some of my extensions and set some settings on every profile after making a new one.
How can I make firefox to pre-install some extensions and set some configs on every new  profile?

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) and Firefox 67.0

Comment: Are those settings and extensions same for every profiles? How about copying those profile folder and set different profile id?

Comment: Use the built-in sync provision.  Choose what kinds of elements you want to copy, pick a profile that's similar, and sync that profile with the new one.  That will get you a starting point close to what you want.  Then disable sync on both profiles, and modify those extensions and settings that will be different.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: yes they are same but not all of extensions are installed on every profile; I just need 4 of them; also I dont want history and tabs, so copying entire profile is not a solution

Comment: For custom configs only, this may help https://superuser.com/a/1326806/726810.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought... You haven't specified *why* you're using so many similar profiles, but if the reason is to keep you logged into certain websites under multiple user accounts (for example, multiple GMail or Twitter accounts) without having to log in and out, then you may find [Multi-Account Containers](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers) more versatile and less cumbersome to manage. Each 'container' basically has its own cookie database and you can customize the name and color of each one.

Comment: Thanks about MAC feature; but no, this not the reason, i use multiple profiles for different tasks (e.g. web programming, browsing, teaching, ...) and new method of tab management of FF makes it use lots of ram , while i still cant close tabs i need to open new fresh FF so i create new profile, the problem is extensions like lastpass, ... need to be installed on all profiles and some settings must be applied ( e.g. disabling tab cycle)