# How to disable automatic updates on Firefox Portable (from PortableApps.com)?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, portable

[image: screenshot]

In the Firefox settings I have disabled automatic updates, but it still downloads them, and my settings get changed back to "automatically install updates". The issue is not specific to this installation. I've done re-installs of it in the past, and the same issue always occurs. The most recent update was done today. I had no knowledge of it, until afterwards when I was greeted with the updated browser start page. I'm using FirefoxPortable from PortableApps.com. Is there another way to disable automatic updates?

Comment: I'm not sure if any of these answers will help, as the question is regarding notifications, but you may find it worth trying: https://superuser.com/questions/1325421/how-do-i-stop-firefox-from-notifying-me-about-updates/1499331