# How to stop firefox update notifications for ver 96.0.3 (64-bit)?

Tags: firefox

I have tried all the approaches here [How to stop Firefox update notifications?](https://superuser.com/questions/1325421/how-to-stop-firefox-update-notifications). None of them works. Some of the settings are even disappeared. I am using version 96 on Debian 9. Upgrade is just not an option here due to none technical reason. So please don't suggest just upgrade, it's easy ....

If I can not find a solution to disable the popup, the only option for me is to down grade the FF version so that I can disable the popup using the proposed solutions in the link.

Comment: The policy method absolutely 100% works. Are you sure you put the file in the correct location?

Comment: [Note that](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-making-automatic-connections#w_automatic-updates-and-security) since v63 the direct option for disabling updates was removed. However as said by @DanielB, many of the answers from the Question linked still works.

Comment: If they don't work you should provide more insight into that fact.  There are comments and answers that have been recently summited.  If they need to be updated we need more information to do so.  What we don't need is multiple questions every time the process changes.

Comment: Downgrading Firefox is not possible without starting over completely.  If you have an older version of Firefox still installed on your system and try to run it, it displays a warning that "Using an older version of Firefox can corrupt bookmarks and history already saved to an existing profile."

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of Firefox 112, mac Sierra, pop ups
"New version is available"

On the desktop create a folder
call it distribution
Open a new file with TextEdit and type
in it
{
"policies":
{
"DisableAppUpdate": true
}
}
Save the file as policies.json (TextEdit allows that)
Put the file policies.json in the folder
distribution

Control+Click and hold on the icon of Firefox.app.
There will be a pop up window with one of options
Show the package contents
Choose it.
The folder Contents will appear.
Click on it.
A few folders will be seen.
One of them is Resources.
Put in the  folder Resources
the folder distribution
Close the windows.
Done

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a slightly older version of Firefox, release 102.8.0esr (32-bit) on Linux and the update popups were driving me to distraction, multiple times per session. Because the software became such junk after March 2020 and keeps crashing and the instability wasn't being fixed by Mozilla, I literally saw the popups dozens of times every day. My installation is set for manual updates only, but none of the suggestions elsewhere on StackExchange to stop the popups has worked. However, I discovered a simple fix in the about:config page today: Change the value in app.update.checkInstallTime.days from the default 63, a few days over two months, to something like 3650, or ten years. Blessed relief!

UPDATE:  Firefox produced an update reminder popup after nearly 12 hours of running continuously without crashing.  The solution isn't perfect, but it is still a huge improvement.  Further, since the program normally would have crashed 8-12 times, it leads me to suspect that the software instability may be directly related to the code that checks for updates.